# Debugging a "There was an error generating the XML document" message

Tags: c#, xml, filestream, xmlserializer

I am having a problem with writing a configuration to an XML file when my database is created from a legacy app. The XML document looks as though it is telling me exactly what the problem is but I can't figure out what it means.

My application allows a user to save a configuration to an xml file from a database and I am using an XmlSerializer and a filestream to write my configuration class to an xml document.

This is the write method in the configuration class

```
    public void Write(Stream stream)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Configuration));

        serializer.Serialize(stream, this);
    }
```

This is the statement calling that

```
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
            {
                config.Write(fileStream);
            }
```

This is all working fine and I am able to save the config file. The problem I have though is that we have a psuedo legacy app which is used to set everything up however if this sets the database then everything loads fine in my application but whenever I try to save the config from one of these databases it causes an **"There was an error generating the XML document"** error message.

I don't really understand how to debug with this. When I look at the generated xml file it just stops mid way through for example

```
  <ServerIPAddress1>127</ServerIPAddress1>
  <ServerIPAddress2>0</ServerIPAddress2>
  <ServerIPAddress3>0</ServerIPAddress3>
  <ServerIPAddress4>1</Ser
```

When I saw this I assumed it must mean that the next property was the value giving it a problem however on both versions that value is blank.

Can anyone give me an idea on where to look with this error. I have tried lots of different things such as loading a configuration which was able to be saved to modifying the xml so it is properly formatted and everything seems to work when I save it to a file again it is all working correctly.

Comment: The `InvalidOperationException` you're seeing is not useful, but the `InnerException` within will be. Go find this and update the question with the message therein.  Also, see [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx).

Comment: When I turned on the clr exceptions it gave me the exact field which was wrong. The old app was setting an enum value to 255 which we didn't have in our version. It was unneccesery anyway so we just removed it and everything works great now! How do I mark your comment as an answer on here?

Comment: The problem property was about 7 or 8 properties ahead of the serverIPAddress4 property. so I would be interested to learn why it decided to stop there. I'm guessing no one will know the answer to this, it will probably just be a microsoft quirk that we all have to suffer through!

Comment: @Keithin8a i changed my comment to an answer, you can check it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, try to get more informations about the exception: is there an innerException?

With Visual Studio, you can try to momentarily throw CLR exceptions to get more informations.

(debug->exceptions->check CLR Exceptions)